# How to express "efficient" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the Esperanto word or expression for ["efficient"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/efficient#English)?

(Note that, although often mixed up with it, "efficient" **isn't the same as** ["effective"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effective#English), which can either mean "actually existing" (eo: [*efektiva*](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/efektiva)) or "having an effect" (eo: [*efika*](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/efika)). "efficient" however refers to –well– efficiency, i.e., how much work or resources are used to reach the effect.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's recap first. Disclaimer: All translations to English are mine and therefore can be off.

- [efekto](http://vortaro.net/#efekto)

  Forta impreso farita sur la psikon, precipe de belarta verko, spektaklo ks: *kia granda efekto ĝi estus!* "what a great effect it would be!"
- efekta

  Faranta konsiderindan efekton: *grandefekta revuo*, "a review/magazine with a great effect"
- [efektiva](http://vortaro.net/#efektiva)

  1 Montriĝanta per konstateblaj efikoj; fakte rezultanta de ies ago: *la vortoj havas efektivan povon*, "the words have have a true impact"

  2 Reala: *vi faris al mi efektivan surprizon*, "you made to me a real surprise"

  3 (antaŭ titolo) En aktiva funkcio: *estis iam efektiva studanto, kiu…* "there was a sometimes active student, who…"
- [efiko](http://vortaro.net/#efiko)

  1 Ago de io efikanta: *saniga efiko de la sunaj radioj*, "the heeling effect/influence of the sun rays"

  2 Difinita fenomeno: *efiko de Edison*, "Edison effect"

  3 La kvociento de la valoro de la grando, kiu estas elmetata kiel utiligebla, per la valoro de tiu, kiu estas ensorbata de la sistemo, plej ofte esprimata per procentoj: *radiada efiko de anteno*, "output of an antenna", "transmission power of an antenna"

Now when it comes to "efficiency" or "how much work or resources are used to reach the effect" as you said, this is quite close to "productivity".

- [rendimento](http://vortaro.net/#rendimento)

  1. Rilatumo inter la utila laboro ricevita de maŝino k la energikvanto elspezita: *altrendimenta motoro*, "an engine with high efficiency"
  2. Efikeco, produktokapablo de maŝino, kampo aŭ homo: *du rizrikoltoj ricevas jarajn rendimentojn de 10 ĝis 12 tunoj/ha* , "two rice harvests yield a crop of 10 to 12 tons per hectare"
  3. Profito akirita per valorpaperoj k kapitalo en la formo de rento, dividendo ks: *la banko… nun strebas al rendimento de 25 el propra kapitalo*, "the bank… now struggles to get a revenue of 25% of own capital"

Depending on the context these might also come to question:

- [efikeco](http://vortaro.net/#efikeco)

  Eco de tio, kio efikas: *kuracilo de granda efikeco*, "a medicine with a great effect"
- [profito](http://vortaro.net/#profito)

  Note that Esperanto word is not restricted to money only: *legi tiun libron alportos al vi multe da profito*
- [gajno](http://vortaro.net/#gajno), gajnaĵo, gajnitaĵo

These can be used to express, what you got, yielded from something.

Comment: Bona respondo! Kvankam uzata, mi evitus _rendimento_ (nek oficiala nek fundamenta) ĉar _efikeco_ tute taŭgas (do, malplia radiko). Fakte la difino de _rendimento_ baziĝas sur _efikeco_.

Comment: If you list the definition of "efecto", I think **also** including that of ["efiko"](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/efiko) would be appropriate, as the latter more closely captures the meaning of the English noun "effect" (or for that matter, the German "Effect" and probably a row of similar words in other languages) which (other than the "efecto" in Esperanto seems to be) isn't limited to the psychological meaning, but can signify any reaction of a system, organism or the world to a cause.

Comment: Mi aldonis "efikon".