# How to express "efficiently" in "express <a meaning> efficiently" in Esperanto?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I recently wanted to state in Esperanto the notion, that

> One should introduce new roots into Esperanto only when the same meaning cannot *efficiently* be expressed using existing roots and affixes.

(emphasis added only to mark the word of interest)

I came up with this partial phrasing:

> Oni enkonduku novajn vort-radikojn en Esperanton nur, se ne eblas ____ esprimi la saman signifon kun jam-ekzistantaj vort-radikoj kaj afiksoj.

I didn't know how to express "efficiently" in that context, thus I asked [How to express "efficient" in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5684/1576). However, I'm not sure, the general translation of the word would be fit for this context, so I'm asking a separate question here, *with* the context:

**How does one express "to express *<something>* efficiently" in Esperanto?**

What would belong in the gap above?

Comment: I encountered **eficienta** so noun and adverb could be derived from that.https://www.wortbedeutung.info/effizient/

Answer (score 2):

**ekonomie** = economically

**efike** = ~ "having that effect"; efikrimede

> ***ekonomio*** = [Reta-Vortaro] Atingo de celo per *plej simplaj* kaj *plej efikaj rimedoj*; *ŝparado*: la scienco estas ekonomio pri pensado; la reguleco de la lingvo donas grandegan ekonomion en la
>   nombro de la vortoj, kiujn oni bezonas lerni EE .

Though this is not what one associates primarily with the word **ekonomio** it fits in the main meaning and finds its uses in national languages ("The dancer moved *economically* through the crowd.") The German *wirtschaftlich*.